# Search by full name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to write a query that finds clients by their full name.

I have a model named Client with first name, last  name, and middle name fields.

I also have this client_full_name method in my User model :

```
def client_full_name
"#{self.Client_fname} #{self.Client_mi} #{self.Client_lname}"
end


# FOR SEARCHES
  def self.search_by_client_full_name(query)
    where("client_full_name like ?", "%#{query}%")
  end
```

I have this in my controller

```
def index
#FOR SEARCHES
if params[:search]
@clients = Client.search_by_client_full_name(params[:search])
else
@clients = Client.all
end
end
```

And I have this in my Index

```
<h2>Search for Clients</h2>
<%= form_tag(clients_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
    Search by Client Name: <br />
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Clients" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :client_full_name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

This is the Error that I keep getting

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: client_full_name: SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients"  WHERE (client_full_name like '%John Smith%')
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Give more code. and your current code is wrong.. You have a method name instead of attribute named inside the `where` clause.

Comment: but how would I go about searching in both the first name , and last name fields?

Comment: Will `query` always contain first, last and middle names?

Comment: yes, the query needs to search for both first name, last name, and middle name if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You method `client_full_name` is an instance method of class `Client`:

```
def client_full_name
  "#{self.Client_fname} #{self.Client_mi} #{self.Client_lname}"
end
```

It ( `client_full_name` ) is not a column(at least it doesn't appear to be) of your clients table. That's why you're getting this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: client_full_name: SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients"  WHERE (client_full_name like '%John Smith%')
```

to make your query work, you need to change your method `search_by_client_full_name` to this(NOTE- Query below will work only for MySQL):

```
def self.search_by_client_full_name(query)
  where("CONCAT_WS(' ', Client_fname, Client_mi, Client_lname) LIKE :q", :q => "%#{query}%")
end
```

For SQLite you can use `||` for concatenation:

```
def self.search_by_client_full_name(query)
  where("(Client_fname || Client_mi || Client_lname) LIKE :q", :q => "%#{query}%")
end
```

But `||` will return NULL if any of the column has NULL, to avoid that you'll have to write `case`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! You actually took the time to explain to me. I appreciate it.

Comment: One more question, what would I put on my index page? instead of <%=       submit_tag "Search", :client_full_name => nil %>

Comment: It can be just `<%= submit_tag "Search" %>` no need of `:client_full_name => nil`

Comment: Thank you. My problem now is that if I enter "John" or "Smith" separately, the record comes up, but if I enter the full name "John Smith" nothing comes up.

Comment: Are you still using SQLite? If yes, then "John Smith" won't come if the middle name is null, as I mentioned `||` will return null/no result if there's any column with null value.

Comment: Yes I am using SQLite. I do have some records that have a middle name, but those records are not coming up either if I type in the full name. They only come up if I type either the first name or the last name or the middle name by itself.

Comment: Weird, I think then the concatenation trick with `||` in SQLite isn't working. :( Just google if there's a way to concatenate columns for where query in SQLite.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solution for your question.

```
patient_first_name_cont = "Ajay"
patient_last_name_cont = "Kumar" 
shared_context = Ransack::Context.for(Request)

search_parents = Request.includes(:request_status).ransack(
    { patient_first_name_cont: patient_first_name_cont }, context: shared_context
  )

search_children = Request.includes(:request_status).ransack(
    { patient_last_name_cont: patient_last_name_cont }, context: shared_context
  )

  shared_conditions = [search_parents, search_children].map { |search| Ransack::Visitor.new.accept(search.base)}

  @req = Request.joins(shared_context.join_sources).where(shared_conditions.reduce(&:and))
```